# VS Debug to a windows phone device?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

My understanding is in visual studio, if i change my debug to 'Remote Machine' I should be able to build and deploy to my phone, and still be debugging it in visual studio.

However, I can't seem to find a guide on how to do this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I specifically have a windows 8 lumia 920 if it matters.

I have VS 2012 on Windows 8 Pro with the WP 8.0 SDK installed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What project type are you using?  It sounds like you may have been using one of the templates for Windows 8 (a Windows Store app), which have the Run dropdown options Simulator, Local Machine, and Remote Machine.

If you are developing for Windows Phone using one of the WP8 templates, the options that you should see in the Run dropdown are Device, Emulator WVGA 512MB, Emulator WVGA, Emulator WXGA, and Emulator 720P.  To debug to your phone in Visual Studio, you need to select "Device" from that dropdown.  Here is an [article with a screenshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff928362(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_DeployingtoaPhysicalWindowsPhoneDevice).

If you have a solution that contains both a Windows Store and a Windows Phone project in it, make sure that you right-click on the Windows Phone project and select "Set as Startup Project".